# NavigationView индикатор счётчика

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout, android-navigation-view

У меня есть индикатор со счётчиком в NavigationView. Мне нужно сделать так что бы индикатор был по середине, а не так как он смещён сейчас в верх. Вариант с установкой отступа, не самый лучший, а

`DrawableLayout.LayoutParams lp = ...
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
 //или
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER`

Не работает, как можно решить данную задачку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: отступ работает не на всех устройствах. `lp.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько это верное решение, но главное что работает;)

```
NavigationView.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Дело в том что сам NavigationView является наследником FrameLayout, а не DrawerLayout как я думал изначально. Упустил такую мелочь, а промучился пару месяцев.